# cat contents of one file into another file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a large (binary) file that has some corruption near the beginning.

Then, I have a second, smaller file that I obtain by starting to download the same file again, but interrupt after I have enough bytes to fix the original one.

My question is, how do I simply overwrite the beginning of the large file with the contents of the second, smaller file? I could use `cat`, `tail` and `head`, but that would create a copy of the file. There must be a more efficient way.

Oh yes, and I'm looking for a linux command-line solution, if that wasn't obvious. I'm using bash, but I have other shells if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dd conv=notrunc if=good_header of=corrupted_file
```

The `conv=notrunc` option is essential here.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed. I keep forgetting that `dd` works on ordinary files as well :) (I can accept your answer in two minutes.)

Comment: Obviously an _awesome_ answer (I was about to write the same thing). `+1`.